# How to html encode in jquery so that '&' dosent appear

Tags: jquery, asp.net, query-string

Serching for encoding text in jquery has given me this function

```
function htmlEncode(value) {
//create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
//then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

This runs ok. but i am passing this value as querystring, and when ever there is '&' sign It just get replaced by '&amp', and when I try to get the querystring via C#(serverside) all text after & get lost.

Note:I am creating querystring on client but needs it on server(IIS)
How can i mitigate this problem. Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
return $('div').html(value).text();
```

And what is `<div/>` i think it would be div

Comment: I need to get it via serverside c# not on client side